# @ManyToMany returns null but the accociation is saved in the database

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I try to retrieve my EquipmentSet from CarEntity but I always get an empty Set despite the database accociation is not empty. I tried to put both releationships to Cascase.All, Cascade.Persist, Cascade.Merge, Fetchpyte.Eager. Everything that I have found on the Internet. The save part as you can see works just fine.

Here is the code. If you need more Information just write me.

'''

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends CarDetails{


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
private Set<Image> imageSet;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "car_equipment",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "car_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "equipment_id")})
private Set<Equipment> equipmentSet = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "car_type_id")
private CarType carType;
}
```

'''

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Equipment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "equipmentSet")
private Set<Car> carSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

[image]